# $H^1$ estimate by $L^2$-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

Let $(\tau_h)$ be a shape regular triangulation. Prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$\|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq \frac{c}{\min_{T\in\tau_h}} \|v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$ for all $v\in V^h$ where $V^h$ is a finite element space.

I know that I have to show the estimate $\|v\|_{H^1(T)}\leq c \|v\|_{L^2(T)}$ where $T$ is the reference triangle. By transformation we obtain the above inequality.

But I don't know how to prove the estimate on the triangle.

Comment: At first I thought $H^1$ was the Hardy space, but it is the Sobolev space.